# checking if list element exists in TCL can't find it

Tags: tcl

i have tcl list of strings

```
set NameList [list 'foo' 'moo 1' 'too 1 3' 'Enterprise 1'] 
and i try to check if "foo" is in the list but i get false
set test "foo"
 if {[lsearch -exact $NameList $test] >= 0} {    
        return 1
  }
```

**UPDATE**
i changed the Double quotes with single quote BUT i set the Variable  test with "foo"
but still it doesn't work

Comment: I have checked this and it is working fine. `lsearch -exact $NameList "foo"` will return 0, which represents the index of the element `foo` in the list `NameList`.

Comment: The curly brackets are used in tcl to wrap string with spaces. In tcl all is a string, even the lists. So you did't do something wrong.

Comment: Single quotes are not a quoting character in Tcl.

Comment: To emphasize what Brad said: single quotes are just plain characters in Tcl. The first element in $NameList is the 5-character string `"'foo'"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try your code, it works exactly correctly for me:

```
% set NameList [list "foo" "moo 1" "too 1 3" "Enterprise 1"] 
foo {moo 1} {too 1 3} {Enterprise 1}
% if {"foo" in $NameList} { puts "got it!" }
got it!
% lsearch -exact $NameList "foo"
0
% lsearch -exact $NameList "not there at all"
-1
```

The auto-quoting of the strings with `{`…`}` instead of `"`…`"` isn't anything you need to worry about. It won't affect the values in the list; they will be exactly the strings you specified.

Oh, and for simple literal value containment tests, do consider the `in` operator as I use it above. It's clearer and says what you mean more. Available in any currently supported release of Tcl (i.e., introduced in 8.5).